# Database Error Occurred: error number 1054 unknown column in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting this error after changed my gmail password. It was working before.

**A Database Error Occurred**

> Error Number: 1054  Unknown column 'g-recaptcha-response' in 'field
>   list'
>
> INSERT INTO `tblsb_userqueries` (`project_id`, `username`,
>   `phone`, `message`, `g-recaptcha-response`) VALUES ('0', 'demo',
>   '0000', 'test', '03AJzQfVCDrIod2TLu')

Filename: models/Common_model.php
Line Number: 8

This is my PHPMailer code:

```
<?php
require 'application/third_party/email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'demo@gmail.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'Demo123#';               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->setFrom('noreply@gmail.com', 'header name');     //Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->addAddress('demo1@gmail.com');  // Add a recipient
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML('Hi, This is my test email');

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

Comment: Whether your table `tblsb_userqueries` have this field `g-recaptcha-response`?

Comment: can you post code where you have used this query

Comment: Yes, this field have in table. Thank you @KMS. one day before my contact form was fully working but today i have changed my gmail password after that i dint get any email in inbox from my website contact form.

Comment: @jigar-shah Please check here error: https://imgur.com/gj9TQQU

Comment: can you please share your code (query) in Common_model.php for insert

Comment: Hello @jigar-shah, please see here code: http://txt.do/d45ni

Comment: that will not help either, can you please share executed query using `$this->db->last_query();` or just make sure you use ` (back-tick) for dashed field name

Answer (score 0):

try below changes, need to change table field name to `g_recaptcha_response`

```
INSERT INTO tblsb_userqueries (`project_id`, `username`,  `phone`, `message`, `g_recaptcha_response`) VALUES ('0', 'demo', '0000', 'test', '03AJzQfVCDrIod2TLu')
```